# Which event will be evoked when pressing categories save button in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

I'm trying to add a new attribute to categories and i wonder which event will be occurred when i press save button?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **catalog_category_prepare_save** event for your need

check following link for more information

**https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html**

Comment: One more question! Do you know which table categories attribute value are saved in database?

Comment: `eav_attribute` here entity_type_id = 3 for catalog_category & take Id from here & find values in `catalog_category_entity_datetime`/`catalog_category_entity_decimal`/`catalog_category_entity_int`/`catalog_category_entity_text`/`catalog_category_entity_varchar`/`catalog_category_product`

Answer (score 2):

On Category save button - **catalog_category_prepare_save** event is called.

**For magento 2.1 All the events listed on below link .**

https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.1-list-of-all-dispatched-events/